# Local Service Fabric with VPN on not working

Tags: c#, vpn, azure-service-fabric

I have a local Service Fabric cluster with 1 node that doesn't work properly when VPN is turned on. I have a catch 22 where I need the VPN to connect to external services while running the cluster in debug mode.

It'll work if I start the cluster without VPN, then after the cluster is started, turn on VPN. This works for some time but as soon as I spin down the cluster (i.e. when I need to re-compile/debug) it won't start back up.

Is there a way to have the VPN turned on where I can spin up/down the cluster like I would in any other normal application development?

Comment: Does your VPN alter your DNS settings while it's running ?

Comment: I'm not sure. If it does what would that mean? And if it doesn't, should it?

Comment: Service Fabric, will set itself as primary DNS. If your VPN also changes your DNS settings, Service fabric will not be able to resolve internal names. Type in command prompt: `ipconfig /all` to get the configuration when it works without vpn, and compare it after you connected with the VPN.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try that. If it does change the DNS should I disable that?

Comment: I guess that would be the VPNs purpose

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options.

1. Disbale the service fabric DNS service, if you are not using service fabric dns I would suggest this.
2. Use alternative DNS
3. Reset your DNS settings after connecting to the VPN and Add all the DNS IP mappings in your hosts file.

#### Option 1

Change your local cluster config. Your clusterconfig is located under: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup`

So if your dev cluster is single node unsecure, you can change: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure\OneNode\ClusterManifestTemplate.json`

In the "addOnFeatures" tag you can remove "DnsService" example:

```
"addOnFeatures": [
   "DnsService",
   "EventStoreService",
]
```

After these steps you can reset your dev cluster from the system tray. (Right click the service fabric icon => Reset Local Cluster)

You can verify if the DNS Service is disabled in Service Fabric Explorer:
[image: sf cluster - dns service]

#### Option 2

1. Open the properties of TCP/IPv4 of your current connection (via Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections)
2. Change the prefered DNS to the one service fabric is using before connecting with the VPN
3. Put the first DNS of the VPN in the Alternate DNS server textbox.
   [image: Connection DNS settings]

#### Option 3

1. Connect to the VPN
2. Find all IP adresses of the FQDN's you need. (You can use ping in command line)
3. Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
4. Add all ip FQDN mappings (1 per line). example: `1.1.1.1 your.company.com`
5. Change your DNS settings to your default configuration.